# javascript downloadUrl with google map not working

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I got the complete code from "google map using PHP/MySQL". when i run the code the google map is display but markers are not there. the following code get the data marker information (latitude, longitude) from xml file.

```
1 function load() {
2  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
3    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
4    zoom: 13,
5    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
6  });
7  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

8  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
9  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {

10   var xml = data.responseXML;
11    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
12    alert(markers.length);
13    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
14    ...
```

"phpsqlajax_genxml.php" is showing proper xml. alert(markers.length) shows 0. what could be the possible error?

Comment: how do you inspect the "proper xml"

Comment: I have accessed "phpsqlajax_genxml.php" file directly from browser.

Comment: Is the phpsqlajax_genxml.php public available, so that we may have a look what's wrong there?

Comment: @Dr.Molle : "phpsqlajax_genxml.php" returns this xml. '<markers><marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/></markers>

Comment: It must also send a correct XML-content-type-header, does it?

Comment: @Dr.Molle: thanks for reply. I have copied the exact code from this site [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3). there is a file named "phpsqlajax_genxml3.php" which i am using to generate xml.

Comment: I have to say this is impossible. The response must be valid xml(otherwise you wouldn't see the alert at all, because accessing `xml.documentElement` would end in an error). As there is also a `<marker/>` inside the XML, the alert can't return 0. I'm afraid this can't be answered without a demo that illustrates the issue.

Comment: @Dr.Molle solved the issue. xml file contain a record which include '&'. by removing that record markers are now showing. thanks a lot for your valuable time